# angular-translate: translate-cloak does not work in v2.4

Tags: angular-translate

I just updated to v2.4 of angular-translate: http://angular-translate.github.io
and found that translate-cloak is not working. It used to work in v2.2.
The 'translate-cloak' class is now never removed from the tag which has the
`translate-cloak` attribute.

I have a plunker to demonstrate the problem:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/NOxGMEqTy4FsZBSIK0zl
```

If it works, it should show two lines. The second line is in a div which has the 
`translate-cloak` attribute.

You can change line 9 of index.html to the line below (change from v2.4 to v2.2 
of angular-translate) to see it works in v2.2.

```
<script src="angular-translate.v2.2.js"></script>
```

Did I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commit 98fe64 is a fix for https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/658 (event was not fired always). Actually it should be fired *MORE often* than before instead of less than before.

Looking at your example, I can see the language seems to be loaded right before parsing the directive and therefor the listener w/ console outputs.

```
console.log('$translateChangeEnd');
```

This means that issue is not related to the change ~success -> ~end, but related to non deterministic (even not in this particular example) order of resource loading, xhr responses and component parsings and compiles.

I've added a

```
$rootScope.$emit('$translateChangeEnd', { language: translation.key });
```

but we have to check if this covers all.

See fork http://plnkr.co/edit/kawPEyjPpPRtJvJzqLeD?p=preview

See my outstanding patch https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/commit/e5ef6ab609d6a58defd371ca8239e8054cab718e

(Disclaimer: I'm from the angular-translate core team.)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/commit/98fe649a241b79c245fb32d838b84f0fac319f5a

I think this is bug caused by above commits.

Actually you replace the '$translateChangeEnd' to '$translateLoadingSuccess' in angular-translate.v2.4.js line 924, it is OK.